# Is there any optimum way to make specific cells editable in Qtablewidget leaving the rest of cells Read only

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

Looking for the optimum way to make the whole table read only by leaving few cells that can be editable.

What i tried is to assign non editable flags to each individual cell except one which needs editing.

```
ui.budget_tab7->item(3,3)->setFlags(ui.budget_tab7->item(3,3)->flags() & Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
```

Well this is not the optimum way to do it.

Is it possible to first make the whole table non editable by doing like this

```
ui.budget_tab7->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

and then applying some sort of method on few cell to make the cell editable??

Comment: Hard to tell if it is the best way, but you may implement your own `QAbstractItemModel` with implements the `flags` method and return editable for every applicalbe cell. Edit triggers are a different concept then editable which cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve here. One option would be to use a [QStandardModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html) in your table. That way you can feed in [QStandardItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html) which are really easy to be configured ( please check all setters for this class to see the real power of it ).

```
QTableWidget* view = new QTableWidget;
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel;
view->setModel(model);
...
QStandardItem* new_item = new QStanrdItem("A");
new_item->setEditable(false);

model->setItem(0,0,new_item);
```

However, it really depends on what your table is going show and also how you want your data to be stored/accessed. Implementing your own QAbstractItemModel is usually the best way to get the desired features.